# Is it right to access external cache in apache spark applications?

Tags: apache-spark, design-patterns, hazelcast

We have many micro-services(java) and data is being written to hazelcast cache for better performance. Now the same data needs to be made available to Spark application for data analysis. I am not sure If this is right design approach to access external cache in apache spark. I cannot make database calls to get the data as there will be many database hits which might affect micro-services(currently we dont have http caching).

I thought about pushing the latest data into Kafka and read the same in spark. However, data(each message) might be big(> 1 MB sometimes) which is not right.

If its ok to use external cache in apache spark, is it better to use hazelcast client or to read Hazelcast cached data over rest service ?

Also, please let me know If there are any other recommended way of sharing data between Apache Spark and micro-services

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-spark which allows to integrate your Spark Application with Hazelcast IMDG via the Spark RDD API.

Comment: As for the data sharing options, it depends on your use case e.g. it can be a distributed cache, queue or just direct calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks @Nazar for your comments. I have already looked at hazelcast-spark project. Though I havent spent much time, I could see only 2 methods(fromHazelcastMap and fromHazelcastCache), there are no methods to access data for given key. Keeping this apart, do you think is this right way to go forward ? Are there any other recommended options I should look at? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Regarding the lookup by key, I believe you can and should use the standard [Java RDD Lookup API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#lookup(K)) in such case. So, to sum-up, if you need to integrate Hazelcast into your existing processing pipeline based on Spark, then the given Connector is your choice. But, please beware of [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-spark#known-limitations) limitation.

Comment: Thanks @Nazar for your inputs. Instead of hazelcast-spark, i could directly use hazelcast java client in spark application, which does not have the limitation you pointed as I will be getting only the value of the specified key. Hope the approach I am taking is right.